# How to prove that $(0,1)^3$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I don't know how to prove that $(0,1)$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}$ and I think it's similary to prove that $(0,1)^3$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

It looks like a trivial but I don't know :/

Maybe use an continuous application ?

Thank you for your help!
Shadock

Comment: Pick $x \in (0,1)$ and find some $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset (0,1)$. A diagram might help.

Comment: $\epsilon = 1/n $ for exemple ? :)

Comment: $\epsilon$ will depend on $x$, @Shadock

Comment: So $x/n$ would be better? :D

Comment: @Shadock: No. Draw a little diagram, this will give you the two lengths from $x$ to 0 and $x$ to 1, both positive. You pick $\epsilon>0$ to be smaller than both. The $\min$ function may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open.

To check this, fix $x \in (0,1)$ and define $\epsilon= \delta/2$, where $\delta=min\{dist(x,0),dist(x,1)\}$. Now, by construction, $x \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)\subset (0,1)$.

$(0,1)^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is open, because it is a finite product of open sets.

Comment: That depends on how you define open on $\mathbb R^3$, but it is generally defined, for beginning students, in terms of the standard Euclidean metric, not the product topology.